# Java upcasting and downcasting and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Let say there is one superclass and two subclasses.

Why Java doesn't allow this scenario:

```
B -> A (A is superclass of class B)
C -> A
ObjectC c = (ObjectC)(ObjectA)b;
```

This way I could map common properties from object b to object c.

Comment: If B is an A, and C is an A, that doesn't mean C is a B. Red is a Colour, Blue is a Colour, Blue isn't a Red.

Comment: How could this possibly work?  If B is neither a subclass nor a superclass of C, then an object is either a B or a C (or neither), but never both.

Comment: Why would you ever attempt this line: `(ObjectC)(ObjectA)b`? When casting, you are casting the reference, not the actual object... the object will always be the type that was created...

Comment: *"This way I could map ..."* - that is not even close to what casting is for, it is not for *mapping* anything.

Comment: @Michael, but Blue and Black share l over Colour ;)
What if subclass variable can hold reference to superclass? What if downcast can extends references? Reverse what upcast do.

Comment: You could use a MapStruct mapper to copy the common base-class fields from an instance of B into a new instance of C.

Comment: @David, thnx, this looking promised. I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

With `(ObjectA)b` you have an expression, if evaluated results in a reference of type ObjectA (ObjectA ab = (ObjectA)b). The actual type of the instantiated object (in memory) does not change, only the handle with you hold it (the reference) changes. You cannot cast that reference to `ObjectC`, because the underlying object instance (originally b) is of type `ObjectB`.

Let's say we allowed what you wrote in the question `ObjectC c = (ObjectC)(ObjectA)b`. If you evaluate that you'd get a reference of type ObjectC to the instantiated object b. Let's say ObjectC has a method called run(), but of course, ObjectB does not have to have a run() method. What would happen when you call `c.run()`?

If you want to map common properties from object b to object c you have to use their common base-class and put common properties there.

Edited with better explanation.

Comment: No, you get _an expression_ of `ObjectA`. The actual object is still exactly the same class no matter how you cast it.